# Hooking up Ecobee smart thermostat

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I purchased a new Ecobee thermostat.  I don't have central air, so heat only.  My gas fired hot water boiler has the wires from the thermostats (Red and White) going to the T1/T1 and T2/T2 terminals.  Looking at the furnace control board, not sure where to hook up the common wire.  The board is an ARGO Technology board.  Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling on said "board"? (It's really a *zone relay* module)

Comment: Can you get us another shot of the "board" with that green wire in the top center of the photo moved aside?